# How to get a child element from xml document in java servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets, document

This is the XML document I get from my server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:createCustomerResponse xmlns:w="{ some namespace :) }">
    <w:usernameTaken />
</w:createCustomerResponse>
```

And this is how I do it:

```
InputStream inputter = connection.getInputStream();
SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document docu = new Document();
try
{
    docu = builder.build(inputter);
} 
    catch (JDOMException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

outputter.output(docu, System.out);
```

So I have a xml document in docu, but i don't know how I can get the value element "usernameTaken"

Answer (score 0):

You can use, any DOM parsing methods.

1. JAVA API, which has getElementsByTagName() type of methods
2. XPath API.

Few links

1. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html
2. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the relevant element using

```
docu.getRootElement().getChild("usernameTaken",
    Namespace.getNamespace("{ some namespace :) }"))
```

using the correct namespace URI from the real document.